# Hide the Text Link in another page which is in Master Page in VB

Tags: html, vb.net, master-pages

I am new to Master pages. As per my project I need to hide the Text Link in another page which is in Master Page. So how can I hide the text link in another page.
I tried with multiple ways but I Could not get it. So, please can any one help on this.

Suppose: In master Page, we have GotoHome link is there. When we click on Home page it should not there. So how can I hide the GotoHome link in Homepage.

I used to display that gotohome with "a href".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to sub-class the MasterPage and add a strong reference to the control you want to manipulate. Otherwise you could use FindControl and CType

Answer (score 0):

You can reference a control on a page's MasterPage by using Me.Master.FindControl. This is assuming the control is directly on the page and not inside a naming container, such as a FormView.

```
Public Class Test
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        CType(Me.Master.FindControl("hl_YourHyperlink"), HyperLink).Visible = False
    End Sub

End Class
```